# if / endif "Unreachable code detected" in C#

Tags: c#, unreachable-code

Everything runs fine locally, but I'm getting an "Unreachable code detected" error.

Here is that piece of code:

```
private string GetRedirectUriForCurrentConfiguration()
{
    #if (DEBUG || DebugDev)
        return "http://localhost:1855/";
    #endif
    return "http://172.16.40.39:1855";
}
```

I'm getting the "unreachable" message on the 4th line, at `return "http://172.16.40.39:1855";`

Is this statement setup correctly?

Comment: Its not an error it's a warning. **If** you are in debug mode `return "http://172.16.40.39:1855";` will be unreachable, that's what the warning is about.

Comment: In Visual Studio on the Ribbon Bar you can switch the build configuration via drop down.

Answer (score 9):

Just add an `#else` preprocessor directive to your code:

```
private string GetRedirectUriForCurrentConfiguration() {

#if (DEBUG || DebugDev)
    return "http://localhost:1855/";
#else
    return "http://172.16.40.39:1855";
#endif  
}
```

Comment: Right. OP's code is the equivalent of 2 consecutive `return` statements when in debug mode. With this, it's one or the other regardless of debug mode or not. Therefore, no warning.